# Problem unexpected element type class when refactor move files in android studio

Tags: android, refactoring

When I refactor move some files in android studio I got problem unexpected element type class. Could anybody help me with answer? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: I added an issue about this to the IntelliJ bug tracker. This is a really annoying one for me as well: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-232083

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is problem or maybe issue of Android Studio. But I try move one by one (package) and it's work fine.

Answer (score -1):

1. Select all your current package's folders and classes and files(everything)
2. Right-Click on one of them and press **F6** on your keyboard
3. On new dialog, click on three dots(...) next to the current package's name and in the new dialog, select the root of your **new** package
4. Click on OK
5. Click on Reflector
6. Done!